# How can a transistor behave as a switch in the saturated region

Tags: electromagnetism

how can a transistor behave as a switch in the saturated region when it is in forward bias mode in the saturation region and the collector current may become zero,

when a transistor is used as a switch im the saturation in region, it is having maximum current but as it is forward biased as it is in the saturation region, the collector current may become zero when the forward bias will be maximum and thereby it will behave as an open switch and will be in the OFF state, where as in the saturation region, it is always ON,

how is it possible, the same we can analyse from the output characteristics of the transistor between collector current and input voltage as given the attached files where the collector current from maximum finally becomes zero,

the confusion comes in 22.30 of the video of mr. h.c verma when he says the collector current may become zero and in 50.30 in the video when he says the collector current is maximum,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXY9zUSulkg&t=2522s

there is a discussion in quora.com on this but was not convincing to me.

https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-transistor-act-as-a-close-switch-in-the-saturation-region

[image]

Comment: Try to read this Jonk answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506349/art-of-electronics-2-5-transistor-saturation/506359#506359  Any more qestion?

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for saturation is \$I_c<\beta I_b\$. Any smaller value for \$I_c\$ is possible, even negative. In saturation \$V_c\$ is low, independent of \$I_c\$, which is just how a closed switch behaves.

Comment: john doty thanks for ur reply, may i know for the transistor to work why do we need a forward biasing in the base emitter region, cant it be done if we connect just a high voltage battery across the emitter and collector, taking to be a npn transistor, the collectors electrons are pulled by the positive terminal of the battery and the electrons on the emitter side are pushed by the negative terminal of the battery, can not it break the potential barrier developed across the base emitter junction ?

Comment: i have one more query, while forward biasing the base emitter junction, we give a voltage just more than the barrier potential what is around 0.7 volt, so if we give say 0.9 volt then 0.7 volt is used in breaking the barrier and the rest 0.2 remains for the current the flow,  does the pn junction diode have any internal resistance as if its not there using ohm's law, v = i r , 0.2 = i x 0, i = 0.2/0 = infinity what cant be,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> as it is forward biased as it is in the saturation region, the collector current may become zero when the forward bias will be maximum and thereby it will behave as an open switch

The only way the collector current will be zero is if the collector voltage is very low - below the V(CE) saturation voltage.

Transistors are not ideal switches. When acting as a switch, they look like a decent low-resistance switch with a voltage source in series as long as the transistor is conducting.

A lower V(CE) saturation voltage is obtained when using the transistor in reverse. The reverse beta is much lower - sometimes below 1.0, and the maximum forward voltage is limited to V(EB), of course.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffq1iY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>